# How is Google's nearby share implemented?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

Google has just released the [Nearby Share](https://blog.google/products/android/nearby-share/) feature on Aug. I'm interested in its technical aspects, but I haven't found any articles on the technical details of Nearby Share. Are there any hints?

I also noticed that Google already has the [Nearby connection API](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) on Android.
This makes me wonder if they have any relations? e.g., is Nearby Share implemented using the nearby connection API?

(Yeah I see that the former is a full-fledged, ready-to-use functionality, and the latter is a API for developers and supports more than file-sharing. But their names look similiar, and so do the communication methods they use, like Bluetooth, BLE, and P2P wifi. )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm the lead of Nearby Share and Nearby Connections at Google.

Yup, Nearby Share is built on top of the Nearby Connections API. Share is the user-facing component of the two, and adds a concept of 'Identity' that Nearby Connections lacks. The reliability & throughput improvements are all a part of Nearby Connections, so users of the API should benefit.

Let me know if you have any specific questions and I'll do my best to answer them.

Comment: Hey Xlythe, do you plan to release APIs for other platforms? I'd like to use Nearby Connections for communicating between my phone and desktops.

Comment: There's a copy of Nearby Connections (C++) available on GitHub (https://github.com/google/nearby-connections), but unfortunately it's a bit complicated to pull all of its dependencies and get it to build. We do want to improve that, but it's a long term effort. The Windows-specific bits are in progress.

Comment: Very exciting. It'd be really sweet if you can release this as a kotlin multiplatform library!

Comment: Is their any library or planning to release one, in case i want to implement the feature in my app

Comment: As mentioned above, Nearby Connections is available through Google Play services on Android, and the C++ library on GitHub supports both iOS and Windows.